# How to launch events from html (webview-ext) and catching them in nativescript?

Tags: javascript, html, webview, nativescript

I'm using webwiew-ext and I want to launch events from webview-ext form to taking data and save it using nativescript script sqlite 
This is the example I have done to test the events but it doesn't work :
my **js** file :

```
function callFromNativeScript() {
    window.nsWebViewBridgee.emit("got", { huba: "hop" });
    console.log("got a message from nativescript");
}
```

Loaded in the html file like that in the header:

```
<script  src="../js/index.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

my nativescript **main.js** file :

```
const Sqlite=require("nativescript-sqlite");
exports.pageLoaded =function(args ){

     page = args.object;
    var db_promise = new Sqlite("test.db", function(err,db) {
        if (err) {
          console.error("We failed to open database", err);

        } else {
            console.log("Is a Sqlite Database:", Sqlite.isSqlite(db) ? "Yes" : "No");
            db.get('select * from test where id=1 ', [1], function(err, row) {
                if(row){
                console.log("Row of data was: ", row); 
                }else if(err)
                {
                    console.log("les guignols");
                } // Prints [["Field1", "Field2",...]]
              });
          // This should ALWAYS be true, db object is open in the "Callback" if no errors occurred
          console.log("Are we open yet (Inside Callback)? ", db.isOpen() ? "Yes" : "No"); // Yes
        }
    });

    window.nsWebViewBridge.on("got",function(message){
      console.log("Salut"+message);
      console.log("hello");
    });
  console.log("bonjour");
}
```

My xml file file :

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded"  actionBarHidden="true" xmlns:nota="@nota/nativescript-webview-ext">

        <nota:WebViewExt src="~/html/index.html"> </nota:WebViewExt>   </Page>
```

Comment: Did you make sure your JS file is being loaded into HTML within WebView?

Comment: Yes it have been done

Comment: I believe in that case your webpack is configured to include the HTML and JS files. Can you share a sample Github repo?

Comment: not sure why I receive error that `window.nsWebViewBridge` throw: `Property 'nsWebViewBridge' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'. any`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [another webview module](https://github.com/Notalib/nativescript-webview-ext)

which has built in functions to execute code within the webview.

Comment: can you share implementation example for the above example ? there's hardly documents on how to use those custom events in that plugin

Comment: my bad, I wrote `let webview: WebView = args.object;` vs `let webview: WebViewExt = args.object;` works great